# How can I move partial changes from an old commit to the working directory?

Tags: git

Given a history of Git commits and a clean working directory, I want to remove some of the changes of a previous commit and apply those changes to my current working directory instead. To clarify, after taking the action the old commit should be modified to only contain the changes that are left, and the following commits will be rewritten. How can I do this the easiest?

Comment: I don't think our community is served when people  change the intent of their question after they have gotten an answer, and decided they don't like the answer.  Significantly editing a question when it can't be answered makes sense.  But changing a perfectly good question to make the answers that have been written no longer apply does not seem to respect the time of those who contribute to the community, nor the idea that we're building a compendium of questions and answers rather than seeking help ourselves.  I'd ask you to think about what community you want to build in the future.

Comment: @SamHartman I understand your concern. In this case, the intent of the question was not changed as my original intent was to ask the question as it is now. I am sorry that my ambiguous formulation caused you to put effort into an answer to a different question and will try to express my questions more clearly in the future.

Comment: With all due respect to @SamHartman, I have to agree with OP here. The question pre-edit already clearly said the intent was to *move* the changes, not copy them.  That this is phrased incorrectly with respect to commit identity is not enough to make an answer about copying the change correct.  If you don't want your time wasted in answering a question, ask for clarification of contradictory questions rather than rushing to get the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

From a clean working tree I'd probably do:

```
git cherry-pick -n old_commit # bring in all the changes
```

At this point, you have all the changes in your working tree but none of them are staged for commit.

```
git add -i
```

## Select the changes you want to keep using the normal git add -i interface

At this point you have all the changes you want to keep staged.  If you want to commit those changes then:

```
git commit #commit staged changes
git reset --hard # remove changes that you didn't accept from your working tree
```

This may leave you with some files that were added in the old commit and that you chose not to add.

Alternatively, if you just want the changes in your working tree, but not staged or committed yet:

```
git commit # we will get rid of this commit shortly
git reset --hard # get rid of changes we didn't accept
git reset HEAD~1
```

The `git reset HEAD~1` will change the index state, discarding the commit we  just made, and leaving us with a working tree that has the changes you decided to keep, but with nothing staged and no new commits.

This leaves the old commit in tact.  So, this answer is useful in the case where you're moving changes across branches or similar.  That is, the changes need to not be present in HEAD.  That happens either if HEAD never contained these changes or if you have reverted them.
It's impossible to change the old commit; Git commits cannot be changed.  It is possible to produce an alternate history where the commit corresponding to the old commit didn't have some of the changes it has in the current history.  That's a different question and so I did not answer it here.

Comment: Thanks, I think this goes in the right direction. However, I'm interested in the case of some old commit that is not the last one.

Comment: @danijar  There was an error in the answer that I fixed.  I assumed that you were talking about a commit that is not the last one; my answer works fine in that case.  It requires that your commit applies to the working tree or that you resolve conflicts at least in parts you want to keep.

Comment: Does your answer also remove the selected changes from the old commit?

Comment: You cannot change an old commit.  Commits are static and can never be changed.  If what you're saying is that you'd like to produce a new history diverging from the old history at the point of the old commit with the changes removed from the old commit and moved into the new commit, I can answer that question, but it is a very different question than the one you asked.  If you ask that question and include a link to it, I'll take a look and answer if someone doesn't get there first.  But that's not the question you asked here.  Revising my answer to say that commits cannot be changed.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant to ask. Of course changing the old commit will require rewriting all following commits. How would I do that? The question reads "remove some of the changes of a previous commit" which I think indicates that.

Comment: I added a sentence clarifying this in the question.